# ArrayFire.jl and chol

Tags: package, julia, arrayfire

I have installed Julia-1.0.0 on a windows 10 box, and then installed [`ArrayFire.jl`](https://github.com/JuliaComputing/ArrayFire.jl). It seems to work (random numbers get generated, and LU factorization seems to work fine). However, `chol` is claimed to be undefined:

```julia
julia> cholesky_fact= chol(a * a')
ERROR: UndefVarError: chol not defined
```

The same error prevents benchmark.jl from running. The other benchmark (nonnegative matrix factorization) also fails, but with a different error (no surprise):

```julia
julia> include("nmf_benchmark.jl")
ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: T not defined
```

Any words of wisdom would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chol` is not defined in julia 1.0.0. It is now in `LinearAlgebra` under the name `cholesky`.

As for the `chol` defined in ArrayFire for `AFArray`s, since it is no longer able to extend `chol` function in Julia which does not exist, the package should instead extend the function `cholesky` or `export` their `chol` function. You may want to create an issue on the `ArrayFire.jl` GitHub repository.

The names of other matrix factorization functions have also been changed.

You should take a look at [the corresponding section in the documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/LinearAlgebra/#man-linalg-factorizations-1).

Also it would help if you use julia 0.7.0 before migrating to 1.0. Julia 0.7 is feature equivalent to 1.0 but with deprecations.

For your other question, it would be better if you could post a separate question with the corresponding code that generates the error.

Comment: Thanks! But I was assuming that ArrayFire was redefining `chol`

Comment: Well, it does define (extend) it for `AFArray`. If you are calling `chol` with a Julia Array, it should return an error, but if you are calling it with `AFArray`, it should successfully call their version. There seems to be no error with it (It calls the C function in `ArrayFire` library). Are you calling `chol` with a Julia array or with an `AFArray`? I think the benchmark does the mistake of calling `chol` with a Julia array and that causes the problem for you.

Comment: I was calling it with an `AFArray, as in:
 a=rand(AFArray{Float32}, 100, 100)

chol(a * a')

Comment: Got it. The problem is that it was *extending* the `chol` function. But the `chol` is not defined in Julia 1.0. Therefore the function should be exported or the package should extend the `cholesky` function. If you are in a hurry, just add `chol` in the `export` list in `util.jl` file of `ArrayFire` package in your `.julia/packages/ArrayFire` directory. Then restart julia, `using ArrayFire` will pre-compile the package again. Then, you will be able to use `chol` for `AFArray`s. Tried it myself. Also edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it. I assume that the suggestion in the actual answer is what I should do if I am NOT in a hurry...